# Netezza delete using JOIN

Tags: netezza

I have two tables in Netezza. Table A have ~70B records and table B have ~15K records. Delete need to happen on table A however I have to join on 2 columns. My query looks like this

Delete from A where (a.col1, a.col2) in (select col1, col2 from B).

I see plan is very costly and looking for alternative approach. Does netezza supports JOIN ON DELETE? Does anybody have any other approach??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rowid` to achieve what you are looking for:

```
delete from table_A
where rowid in (select a.rowid
from table_A a inner join
table_B b
on a.col1=b.col1
and a.col2=b.col2)
```

Comment: I see plan going in diff direction now; exploring "exists" options.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use EXISTS() as an alternative syntax:

```
delete from table_A a
where exists(select 1 from table_b b
    where b.col1=a.col1
      and b.col2=a.col2
)
```

Edit:
The overhead of this is fairly low because it doesn't have to build the join or collect anything, it just has to check if the record is there.

Comment: This is more generic and better than the actual answer from my point of view since it does not mandate the presence of a unique key (which was my case).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to create a table using CTAS without the records and rename it .I believe the cost incurred will be less here .

```
create table T1 as select 
col1,col2 from A where (col1,col2) 
not in (select col1,col2 from B);

drop table A;

alter table T1 rename to A;
```